# Linux - RED HAT 7 (RHEL7) - No funciona yum

Tags: linux

Estoy tratando de instalar gcc con el comando: yum install gcc* y falla en todos los casos. Tambien intento con : yum groupinstall "Development Tools" y exactamente lo mismo.
El error es siempre el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mismo pasa con cualquier paquete que necesite bajar.
Alguien me podria guiar en que podria estar pasando?
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Para tener acceso a la descarga de paquetes debes registrarte y activar tu red hat.

Comment: Excelente, faltaba registrar!!! Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda @Igmer Rodriguez